# I want to create an if statement in a public sub to open a specific query based on button click

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am wanting to consolidate my VBA so it is easier to manage and see rather than duplicating it several times.
I would like to then write an if statement inside of the sub that opens the recordset based on the button I click
There are 4 buttons
`cmdAllSuppliers` `cmdActive` `cmdInactive` `cmdArrangments`
Each button has the VBA that calls the sub `EmailQuery` and error handling. the sub code is as follows.

```
Sub EmailQuery()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strEmail As String
    Dim strQryAll As String
    Dim strQryActive As String
    Dim strQryInactive As String
    Dim strQryArrangement As String

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    strQryAll = "qryAllSuppliers"
    strQryActive = "qryActiveSuppliers"
    strQryInactive = "qryInactiveSuppliers"
    strQryArrangement = "qryAgreementEmail"

    rs.Open strQryAll, cn
    rs.Open strQryActive, cn
    rs.Open strQryInactive, cn
    rs.Open strQryArrangement, cn

    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            strEmail = strEmail & .Fields("Email") & ";"
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    strEmail = Left(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - 1)
    
    DoCmd.SendObject , , , , , strEmail, , , True, False

End Sub
```

The rs.open will obviosly not work how it currently is but I would like the if statement to open one of those four based on which button I press.

Comment: You appear to have a grip on VBA.... you just need to pass a parameter/argument to your routine. ie( sub FunctionName(SelectedInteger As Integer) and then use that with your 'if' statements to run the query you want.

Comment: I wouldn't say I have a good grip of it. It's more just being very good at googling and then adjusting slightly to suit my data and names etc. Which is why I am stumped sort of as to how exactly I would do it.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to skin a cat with this task. You could add buttons/dropdown to the ribbon, a form or a worksheet.  
One way, I think, quite simple, in the developer tab, look for 'insert', select a button, right mouse click, assign a macro. Write four macros which call the macro above with the argument you want to use. Not pretty but it would work...

Comment: I haven't got the time to answer this in detail and it would be rewriting the wheel... If you google 'call macro for dropdown in excel', you will get clear instructions for what  you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub EmailQuery(strQueryName as string)

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strEmail As String
   
    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strQueryName, cn
    With rs
   .movelast 
   .movefirst


        Do While Not .EOF
            strEmail = strEmail & .Fields("Email") & ";"
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    strEmail = Left(strEmail, Len(strEmail) - 1)
    
    DoCmd.SendObject , , , , , strEmail, , , True, False

End Sub
```

```
'EmailQuery is a sub so no () around parameters
Private Sub cmdAllSuppliers_Click()
EmailQuery strQryAll 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is giving me a compile error "ByRef argument type mismatch"

Comment: Okay so I have fixed that Issue I think `Private Sub cmdAllSuppliers_Click()
    EmailQuery (qryAllSuppliers)
End Sub`
I now get command text was not set for the command object on the `rs.Open strQueryName, cn` line

Comment: Just had to put quotes around the Query Names in the Private subs. Solved the problem and what I was wanting to do. Now there is just an issue with one of my queries that is making me want to pull my hair out...